# In C++,is it possible to define a class used as: SomeObj obj1; SomeObj<4> obj2;

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I want to implement a string class which has an option to create the inner buffer on stack or heap. So that I think about the appearance of that string like:

```
String str_on_heap;
String<512> str_on_stack;
```

will be elegant. But, latter I find that it is hard to implement such an interface in C++.

```
template < int StackBufferSize = 0 >
class String {
    ... // Codes to implement String on stack.
};

template <>
class String< 0 > {
    ... // Codes to implement String on heap.
};

String str_on_heap; // Compile error, should be "String<> str_on_heap;"
String<512> str_on_stack; // OK.
```

Does any one has an idea or other C++ tricks to offer such an interface?

Comment: Sounds like a bad design choice

Comment: You should really use two different classes. Anyway, if you want to do that, you may use template specialisation and static_if<>

Comment: @hwlau, It is possible to use just one class, http://www.drdobbs.com/184405453

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `String` class is a template, you always need to use the `<>` notation when referring to the class.

What you can do is write a template specialization for the case when `StackBufferSize == 0`, which will use the heap.

```
template <int StackBufferSize = 0>
class String
{
  // code to allocate string on the stack
};

template <>
class String<0>
{
  // code to allocate on the heap
};
```

This way, when you declare `String<>` it will use the specialization for the heap.

That said, this is probably not a good design decision.  A better solution would probably be to just use `std::basic_string` and provide a custom allocator if you really need to avoid heap allocations.

Comment: Thanks Charles. But I'm trying to use the String like: "String str;" Not "String<> str;". I don't think use "String<> some_str;" every where is elegant.

Comment: @zJay, that is not possible if you intend to use the same class name.

Comment: anyway, just because you don't like the fact that it's not possible what you want to do is not a reason for a downvote. +1 from me...

Comment: Sorry Charles. I'm new here and I don't quite familiar with these rules and the operations.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you want is, to my knowledge, impossible to obtain : you want `String` to be simultaneously a class and a class template.

Just to provide an alternative to specialization on a given size, I believe you should take a look on [Policy Based Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design), and provide policies such as :

```
String<HeapStorage> heapStr;
String<StackStorage<512> > stackStr;
```

From my point of view, this is better design : better read, better understood without looking at the implementation, and does not rely on an 'invalid size' magic value.

Comment: Thanks icecrime, but there's a lot more to write and personally I prefer some clean code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
 const int HEAP=-1;
 template<> class String<HEAP> {
     //... specialization for Heap
 };

 String<HEAP> str_on_heap;
```